# Python cannot import name 'find_namespace_packages' from 'setuptools' package

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, importerror

I'm currently creating a python library and need to use the 'find_namespace_packages' from the 'setuptools' package. However python throwing out the following ImportError message whenever it runs:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_namespace_packages' from 'setuptools'
```

However it has no trouble importing the other functions from 'setuptools' like 'setup' and 'find_packages'.

How do I troubleshoot it?

I have uninstalled and reinstalled 'setuptools' multiple times already and updated Spyder and Anaconda.

Also here is a sample of my code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages

setup(

      name="sample",

      version="0.0.1",

      packages=find_namespace_packages()

      )
```

I am currently using Python 3.7.5 and setuptools is on version 49.6.0

Comment: Something wrong with package, try to run `pip install -U setuptools`.

Comment: Maybe you are using another python interpreter accidentally ?  find_namespace_packages() was introduced with version v40.1.0 of setuptools

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the question's comments, the solution is to run

`pip install -U setuptools`

And afterwards retry installing all the packages, e.g.

`pip install -e .`