# How to solve this error ImportError: cannot import name 'StaticModule' from 'setuptools.config'?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install a python package with `pip install .`, but during installation, it throws an error:

**Update:**

```
  File "/Users/user/miniconda3/envs/galaxy-lab/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/private/var/folders/8w/ldbd6zrd2dd87g6vlckzjn193kdndm/T/pip-build-env-07a9m59q/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_packaging/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .setupbase import *
  File "/private/var/folders/8w/ldbd6zrd2dd87g6vlckzjn193kdndm/T/pip-build-env-07a9m59q/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_packaging/setupbase.py", line 37, in <module>
    from setuptools.config import StaticModule
ImportError: cannot import name 'StaticModule' from 'setuptools.config' (/private/var/folders/8w/ldbd6zrd2dd87g6vlckzjn193kdndm/T/pip-build-env-07a9m59q/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/__init__.py)
```

**Update**

**python package**

`https://github.com/g2nb/nbtools/tree/lab`

**pip version**

`pip 21.2.4`

**Python**

`python 3.9`

I tried to reinstall the `setuptools` and `jupyter_packaging`, but it didn't solve the problem.

How to resolve this issue?

thanks

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628850/python-cannot-import-name-from-setuptools-package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python cannot import name from 'setuptools' package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628850/python-cannot-import-name-from-setuptools-package)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tested this but it doesn't work.

Comment: @jax We might need a lot more details in order to be able to help you. What are you trying to install? What is your version of pip?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/6056#issuecomment-836978448 : "*`jupyter_packaging` requires `setuptools` >= `46.4.0` - which is when `StaticModule` was added. Could you please ensure you're running the minimally-required version and retry your startup?*"

Comment: @phd Yes, I ensured everything, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setuptools 61 moved `setuptools.config.StaticModule` to `setuptools.config.expand.StaticModule` (see [#365](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3065)). This bug was reported to the jupyter-packaging developers in [#130](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter-packaging/issues/130) and fixed in [#131](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter-packaging/pull/131) which was first included in jupyter-packaging 0.12. So either downgrading to setuptools 60 or upgrading to jupyter-packaging 0.12 should fix your issue.

Comment: yeah, I figured this. thanks a lot.